# How to retrieve title and url of a openned com.google.gwt.user.client.Window

Tags: gwt

I opened a window with `com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.open()`
How to retrieve the title and URL of this new window after navigating in it ?

After openned a new window with "http://www.google.com" and searching "Stackoverflow" the **title** become "Stackoverflow - Google Search" and the **URL** change to "http://www.google.com/&q=stackoverflow"
I would like to **retrieve these two informations** in the parent window.

**How do I do it with GWT ?**

Example :

```
private void myMethod() {
  Window.open("http://google.com", "Google")
  // ... searching "Stackoverflow"

  Button b1 = new Button(getTitleOfPopupWindow()); // Stackoverflow - Google Search
  Button b2 = new Button(getUrlOfPopupWindow()); // http://www.google.com/&q=stackoverflow
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you open a new window, it becomes a totally different window that your app cannot access - unless you have total control over its contents (i.e. it's on your domain). It would be a huge security and privacy hole if an app in one browser window/tab had access to the information in all the other windows/tabs.

You can let your users open an iFrame within your app and see where they navigate within that iFrame, if your users don't mind it.

If you have a total control over the new window, then you can insert a script in the child page to call the parent page using Window.opener. However, it looks like this is not your use case.

Comment: In JS, a window can refer to his parent window with window.opener (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.opener) so I think it is possible with GWT